# how to configure the table at runtime in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

people know that we can use if statement to configure a query in the select statement like this

```
select if(var=1,amount,amount/2) from mytable;
```

But what if I want to achieve something like this:

```
select amount from if(var=1,mytable1,mytable2);
```

Is there any way to configure the table at run time?

Comment: Where does `var` come from?  If it's a variable in another language, you could test it in that other language and then construct different SQL as appropriate.  If it's a user variable in SQL, you could similarly use an [`IF` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if-statement.html) around the two alternative `SELECT` statements.

Comment: It is from another language which will call this sql file and pass in the variable and I want to keep only one sql file.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "I want to keep only one sql file".  See the first option under my answer below.

Comment: oh what I mean is: I can write two sql files using different tables and modify my caller to call different table depending on the variable var. But I am not gonna do that. I just want to use only one sql file and pass the var into the sql file and the sql file can distinguish the variable which was passed in by the caller and then use the appropriate table accordingly.

Comment: But **why** do you want to do it that way?  If you absolutely must, you can use the SQL `IF` statement shown in the second option in my answer with your externally passed-in variable.  But that is, IMHO, utterly bizarre.

Comment: well I have to do that way due to restrictions.

Comment: What restrictions?  Care to elaborate?  We're quite good at finding workarounds to such things.  In any event, as I said, you can use the second option shown in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT amount FROM mytable1 WHERE @var = 1
UNION
SELECT amount FROM mytable2 WHERE @var = 0
```

**UPD:** Here's what MySQL `EXPLAIN` looks like for the part of the query which has a condition evaluating to `FALSE`:

[image]

Note the `Impossible WHERE` part. MySQL recognizes that the expression in `WHERE` is constantly evaluating to `FALSE`, so it doesn't even try executing the query. Hence, no performance overhead when using this approach.

Comment: you were right about my anwser, so I removed it. But I think the exact solution can't be found without the exact problem.

Comment: Hi Shedal, I have question for your solution, if @var is 1 will the second query under UNION execute by fetching same amount of data as normal? I am considering the efficiency issue.

Comment: @PeitiPeterLi Obviously, in case @var = 1, the second query will not fetch anything, because for each row, the condition is not met. In fact, MySQL will optimize it and skip the whole query, since it has a constant FALSE condition. I just checked it, also in a `UNION`, (MySQL 5.0.90) and it does not hurt performance at all.

Answer (score 1):

(*Upgrading to an answer*)

**Where did `var` come from?**

1. If it's a variable in another language, you could test it in that other language and then construct different SQL as appropriate:

   ```
   $sql = "SELECT amount FROM " . ($var = 1 ? "mytable1" : "mytable2");
   ```
2. If it's a user variable in SQL, you could similarly use an [`IF` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if-statement.html) around the two alternative `SELECT` statements:

   ```
   DELIMITER ;;

   IF @var = 1 THEN
     SELECT amount FROM mytable1;
   ELSE
     SELECT amount FROM mytable2;
   END IF;;

   DELIMITER ;
   ```
3. If it's anything else (like a field from your tables), then your question doesn't make a great deal of sense.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the mysql manual pages, it appears you cannot do this with the traditional syntax.

"User variables are intended to provide data values. They cannot be used directly in an SQL statement as an identifier or as part of an identifier, such as in contexts where a table or database name is expected, or as a reserved word such as SELECT."
- [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html][1]

The exception to this is that you can assemble a prepared statement, but is probably not a better solution for most programming tasks. It would be better to leave the sql string generation to the language invoking mysql.

But, if you are doing this as part of a "sql only" task, like an import, this seems to be the approach you must take.

```
SET @s = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM ", if(true, "table1", "table2"), " LIMIT 1");
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

SET @s = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM ", if(false, "table1", "table2"), " LIMIT 1");
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```